# Angular: Are template components case sensitive

Tags: html, angular, dom

This is a follow up question from an earlier post. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179933/get-value-of-select-using-only-reactive-form) I ran into a problem where I could not get the value from a `<select>` element. The solution turned out to be embarrassingly simple. Use lowercase `<select>` in the Angular template instead of uppercase `<SELECT>`.

[image]

**We all know HTML is case insensitive, which leads me to my question.** Why was I unable to get the value of the select when the element was `<SELECT>`, **are Angular templates case sensitive?**

**When I inspect the element in the DOM** regardless of whether I used `<SELECT>` or `<select>`, **the element is always rendered in lowercase.** Which from my understanding is expected standard browser behavior. This further leads to my suspicion that the behavior I experienced is a result of something Angular is doing.

I've scoured the internet trying to find an explanation for this, but have been unable to find an explanation. Almost immediately after asking the original question, user JBNizet, was able to  point out my mistake in the HTML. It is that level of insight and understanding of the relationship between HTML templates and Angular I am trying to gain.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when using `SELECT`? `No value accessor for form control with name: 'MATERIAL'`?

Comment: That is part of the problem that I don't understand. If I simply make it lowercase `<select>`, then that error goes away and everything is happy. Which is why I am curious if Angular has some kind of case sensitivity issue going on with HTML elements.

Comment: It means that angular directive selector is case-sensitive https://ng-run.com/edit/6rqY5FznGARcV7iO2hFm

Comment: Now take a look at control value accessor for select tag https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b26a90567c4e95e833e8ee00882fc28910def20e/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L94 If we use SELECT angular can't determine directive for that tag

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, but Javascript is not. And Angular is basically just Javascript generating the DOM on the fly, so...

Comment: Angular compiler use an HTML parser that is case sensitive when compiling component templates

Comment: @NoémiSalaün you could add this as an answer (with additional link to docs where this is specified) - remember to quote the relevant bits of the docs into your answer

Comment: I read it long time ago, when browsing the source code to see how Angular parse its template, I don't think there is anything in the doc. That's why I have posted my answer in the comments

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It all was very helpful in understanding what is really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are template components case sensitive?

Yes, the templates are case-sensitive in Angular. You have to write `ngIf`, for example, in order to trigger parsing it as a directive with the selector `[ngIf]`. `ngif` or `NGIF` would not work.

Using `SELECT` works as expected wihout a problem. The culprit is the control value accessor for the select element, which has a selector specified as something like `select[formControlName]`, which does not match `<SELECT formControlName=foo>`.